# PHP DI container - reading what objects the constructor requests

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I need to make a DI container which will automatically inject the needed dependencies.

I only have one idea to do this,
Lets say i have initialized a controller using the container, the container will get the namespace of that object and then it will detect what dependencies it requests. The container should get the namespaces of the dependencies that needs to be injected, and then it will create them, then create a new object witg these depndencies and return it.

But the question is, how can you check what dependencies the constructor requests in php?

Comment: Reflection helps. By the way, why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There are already great DICs like Auryn.

Comment: To understand how things work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ReflectionFunction::getParameters()` or `ReflectionMethod::getParameters()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php) return an array of [`ReflectionParameter` instances](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php).

Now on the `ReflectionParameter` instances you can use [`ReflectionParameter::getClass()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getclass.php) to get the classes you need.

To get the class' name, you need to access the `name` property of that `ReflectionClass` which was returned by `ReflectionParameter::getClass()`.